# Avoid using arrays (and [0]) in multidimensional JSON object

Tags: arrays, json

I'm storing data in a JSON file and need different objects/arrays. So far I am using the following structure:

```
data= [
  {
    "savedRuns": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Run 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Run 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Run 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "g1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "g2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "g3"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "locations": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "home"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "work"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "school"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to access the data in the file in an easy way, for instance:

```
console.log(data.savedRuns)
console.log(data.locations)
```

Unfortunately this returns `undefined` and the only way to access the data is:

```
console.log(data[0].savedRuns);
console.log(data[2].locations);
```

Since I don't necessarily know the position of the object, I would like to avoid that. If there a way around this, or a different structure to adopt for my file?

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javo/85xaonwv/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have each attribute in a separate object, stored in an array. Get rid of the outer array and store the attributes in one object, then use `data.savedRuns`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marks answer I could get the right syntax. Posting below in case of interest to others.

```
data = {
    "savedRuns": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Run 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Run 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Run 3"
        }
    ],
    "groups": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "g1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "g2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "g3"
        }
    ],
    "locations": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "home"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "work"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "school"
        }
    ]
}
```